# Determining if Function is 1:1 or Onto

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to solve the following question:

> Given function $ \displaystyle f\colon \mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Z,$ where $f(n) = \lfloor {\frac {n}{3}} \rfloor$, determine if it's $1:1$, and onto; and prove why.

I could say that it *is* onto, because it will always have an element in the codomain that maps to the domain. It is also *not* one to one, because the floor would result in multiple numbers with the same floor (like $ \frac {1}{3}$ and $ \frac {2}{3}$ both having the floor $0$). But how can I actually prove these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the definition of $1$-$1$ function. See what happens, when you plugin $3$ and $4$ to $f$. You have $$f(3) = \biggl\lfloor{\frac{3}{3}\biggr\rfloor} = 1 = \biggl\lfloor{\frac{4}{3}\biggr\rfloor}=f(4)$$

but $3 \neq 4$ hence it is not $1$-$1$. Note that if you want to prove a function is one-one, then you have to show whenever $f(a)=f(b) \Longrightarrow a=b$.

To prove that it is onto, for each integer $n$ we want integer $m$ such that $\bigl\lfloor{\frac{m}{3}\bigr\rfloor} = n$. Doesn't $m=3n$ finish the job?

Comment: So since m=3n is a Real number, then it is onto?

Comment: @Christopher: It's an integer.  Yes :). To see it give me an $x$. Say $3$, then i have 10 in $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(10)=3$. Next, give me 5 then i have 15 in $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(15)=5$. For ontoness you have to show there is $y in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(x)=y$ for some $x \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT** $\rm\ \ \ \#\ f^{\:-1}(k)\ =\ \#\:\{\: n\ :\ k\:\le\: n/3\: <\: k+1\}\ =\ \#\:\{\: n\ :\ 3\:k\: \le\: n\: <\: 3\:k+3\}\ >\ 1$

Answer (score 1):

You already have done most of the work.

To prove that it is not one to one, you just need a counterexample, which you already have.

To prove that it is onto, for each integer $n$ find (explicitly) an example of an integer $m$ such that floor $m/3 = n$.

Comment: Ok, so to prove that its ONTO, how can I prove that each n has a corresponding m/3? I haven't proved (or disproved) any floor/ceiling functions before.

Comment: @Christopher:   One way, which works here, is to say that if I give you an $m$, you can always find an $n$ such that $f(n)=m$.  You prove that by saying "and $n=3m$ (or $n=3m+1$) works".